# I working on sharepoint website

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

All Pages Scrolling is very slow using all iOS devices. Please provide me fix. 
whats is fix for this js or css?

Answer (score 1):

Followup questions:

1. Are you using the application or the browser? If so, what type?
2. What version of SharePoint? (If you are unsure, you can check [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/which-version-of-sharepoint-am-i-using-3575ff57-037f-48cf-9398-99080c34b25f))